# importing MySQL database in shared hosting

Tags: mysql, laravel

[image]I am importing a MySQL database in shared hosting but I am unable to import the structure of tables properly. After importing, for all tables, there are no primary and foreign keys are coming only data is imported. In between, I will get an error like

> 1071 - Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes

Comment: Does this answer your question? [laravel migration Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52370510/laravel-migration-specified-key-was-too-long-max-key-length-is-767-bytes)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [#1071 - Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814532/1071-specified-key-was-too-long-max-key-length-is-767-bytes)

Comment: No, I have tried this. I am unable to import the MySQL database completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this to you AppServiceProvider.

```
use Schema;
```

then add this to `boot()` function

```
Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
```

However if you really want to maximize the 255 VARCHAR default length of your database. you need to manage your database setting first.

Comment: if 255 link doesn't matter to you. you can add the schema setting to your AppServiceProvider class.

Comment: what mysql version are you using. i'll guess . its Mysql 8 ?